# Java SwingWorker does not work in a main method?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I just try following code but the swingworker is not executing. If I put it in an action of a GUI application (in a button click event) it is executing. What is the technical reason for that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("do in background.....");
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

}
```

Comment: What do you excpect to happen and what happens instead? When i run this code, it prints `do in background.....` and then finishes

Comment: i expected the 'do in background' message on the console. but it won't.

Comment: Strange. If i run this with 1.8_u60 i get what you expect

Comment: oooops i'm using 1.7

Comment: `SwingWorker` has been available since 1.6.

Comment: I just tested it in 1.7.   It printed "do in background" and worked as expected.  Are you using javax.swing.SwingWorker?

Comment: SwingWorker uses daemon threads - it can happen that your main method returns (and exits the application) before SwingWorker had time to start and execute your background method.

Comment: `SwingWorker` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) states the following about it: *An abstract class to perform lengthy GUI-interaction tasks in a background thread.* You do no GUI-interaction tasks, since you define no GUI. That would be your technical reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Concurrency in Swing: Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.

It works after adding `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                            System.out.println("do in background.....");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }.execute();

                }
            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a timing issue. If the background task finishes before the main method it will print "do in background......":

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("do in background.....");
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

    Thread.sleep(100L);
}
```

If however main finishes before the background task had a chance to run, it will print nothing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(100L);
            System.out.println("do in background.....");
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

}
```